# How to add custom search tools for custom component

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-component

I have created Custom component from component-creator website now I want to add Search tools to this component, Search component like Article search provides.
can anyone guide me from where I can add this functionality.

What I have done is add a custom filter code to `view.html.php` as shown below:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT countryname as x FROM sugee_sugee_country where state=1 ORDER BY id ASC";
$db->setQuery($query); 
$rows = $db->loadObjectList(); 
$options = array();
$this->state->get('filter.countryname');
foreach ($rows as $row) {
      $options[] = JHtml::_('select.option', "$row->x", JText::_($row->x));
}

JHtmlSidebar::addFilter(
    '- Select Country -',
    'countryname',
    JHtml::_('select.options',$options,'value', 'text', $this->state->get('filter.countryname'), false));
```

My problem is that it does not work properly it always refresh the page and it does save its state like if i select INDIA then it should save INDIA as default. but it is not working and records are also not showing properly.

I have to create any other files for this or i have add any code or function anywhere else ?

Please guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are part way there. Have a look in your components model for the **getListQuery()** function. That is where the filter will be applied to the list before it is sent back to the view.

In the same file is a **populateState()** function where you can get filter.countryname from the request and set it before the page is displayed.

Have a look at how this is done in com_content/models/articles.php for guidance on how to apply it to your code.

Comment: Thanks john, I have done the same and got the solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

This probably is late reply but it might help others who are looking to add search tools on list view in Joomla backend.

[Using 'Search Tools' on Joomla 3.x at admin backend for list views](https://techjoomla.com/developers-blogs/joomla-development/joomla-using-jlayouts-search-tools-on-joomla-3-x-at-admin-backend-for-list-views)